# How can I link the source path of a compiled library to a different location in Eclipse?

Tags: c, eclipse, elf, eclipse-cdt, msp430

I've installed the msp430-gcc compiler and associated tools to do some open-source msp430 development at home using Eclipse. I'm developing on a slightly older Macbook Pro running OS X Lion and installed the tools using MacPorts. I'm running Eclipse 3.7.2 with the CDT and GCC Cross Compiler Support plug-ins. I have a simple empty main() written that compiles and links just fine.

The ELF parser lets me view the contents of the ELF binary just fine with the exception of one component; when I try to view the contents of the startup code in crt0.S, it gives me a blank file. When I click on the crt0.S component of the ELF, the filename bar at the bottom of the Eclipse window shows `"/opt/local/var/macports/build/_Volumes_work_mports_dports_cross_msp430-gcc/msp430-gcc/work/gcc-4.6.3/gcc/config/msp430/crt0.S"`. This makes sense because of my MacPorts install of msp430-gcc. `crt0.S` is archived into `/opt/local/lib/gcc/msp430/4.6.3/libcrt0.a on my machine.`

What I want to be able to do is tell Eclipse to look elsewhere for the source files for the libraries that are automatically linked when I build with the msp430-gcc toolchain.  This would presumably include everything in `/opt/local/lib/gcc/msp430/4.6.3/`. I started by downloading the source for mspgcc-20120406 (the version in my MacPorts install) and applying the gcc patchfile to an empty directory tree. This created the `gcc/config/msp430` directory, including the `crt0.S` and `crt0ivtbl.S` files.

What I have had no luck accomplishing is telling Eclipse to look in `~/Developer/mspgcc-20120406/gcc-4.6.3/config/msp430/` instead of the path that's in the already-built `libcrt0.a`. I tried playing around with the `Project Preferences->Paths and Symbols->Source Location` window, but didn't have much luck. I searched through this website and on Google and the closest thing I came up with was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784543/how-to-attach-source-to-the-libraries-on-eclipse-cdt) but it doesn't "smell" like the right answer.

I would like to avoid solutions that involve moving the library source into my project. I'd rather have a solution that will work for multiple projects.

All help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try and check if the Eclipse **[linked resource](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/concepts-13.htm)** could help you declare that external directory from within your Eclipse project here.

> Linked resources are files and folders that are stored in locations in the file system outside of the project's location. These special resources can be used to add files and folders to your project that for some reason must be stored in a certain place outside of your project. For example, a linked folder can be used to store build output separately from your source files.

I find interesting how you can define that linked resource:

> Linked resource target paths can be either defined as absolute paths, or **relative to a path variable**.

[image: linked resource relative to a path variable]

Since you can define it relative to (for instance) your Eclipse *project location* `PROJECT_LOC`, you can then setup your resource in a way which won't change between two environments.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This appears to allow me to do something like create a `msp430-gcc-libsrc` folder in my project and link it to `~/Developer/mspgcc-20120406/gcc-4.6.3/config/msp430/`, which unfortunately I don't think will accomplish what I need.

I need some way to tell the ELF parser (at a minimum) that if it tries to look in `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_Volumes_work_mports_dports_cross_msp430-gcc/msp430-gcc/work/gcc-4.6.3/gcc/config/msp430/` it should instead look in `~/Developer/mspgcc-20120406/gcc-4.6.3/config/msp430/`; essentially I need to alias one to the other.

Comment: (Continuation of previous comment). I couldn't see a way in the Eclipse documentation on Linked Resources to make that happen

Comment: @ryan OK, it was worth mentioning, just in case.