# Best git structure for importing android dependent project with egit in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, git, dependencies, egit

How can I easily import the whole reposition from git (bitbucket) using [EGit](https://www.eclipse.org/egit/) in Eclipse that contains 3 Eclipse projects (one end-project and two library projects) into default git folder, if my Eclipse workspace folder already contains library projects?

After warning on the picture:

[image: import projects existance]

My libraries projects are not found because they are in a different folder than the library projects. I would like to avoid putting my git local reposition in eclipse workspace or changing `project.properties` to link to the absolute path of libs.

[image: missing lib projects]

[image: folder structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> or changing project.properties to link to absolute path of libs.

That is actually a good solution, since you can declare a library:

- **[relative to a project location](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10972636/6309)** (or the workspace location),
- or using **[linked resources](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/concepts-13.htm&resultof=%22Linked%22%20%22link%22%20%22resources%22%20%22resourc%22)**, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10353544/6309) (and this [blog post](http://taglist.blogspot.fi/2011/08/eclipse-tricks-relative-paths-in-linked.html))

[image: linked resource target]

That should help allowing you to import only `TwistedCircle`, because its properties would refer to other projects relative to the project or the workspace folder.